# How to prevent adding duplicates to many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many-to-many table with `UserId` and `TaskId`
When I add data to the table I can add the same UserId and TaskId more than once.

I use the following query to add the data:

```
Create table if not exists user_task(UserId INT, FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
REFERENCES USERS(id), TaskId INT, FOREIGN KEY (TaskId) REFERENCES TASKS(id));
```

How can I prevent adding duplicates of those in the table?

```
+-----------------+
| UserId | TaskId |
+-----------------+
|   1     |   1   |
|   2     |   1   |
|   1     |   1   |
+---------+-------+
```

I know I can put `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` query to get the data without duplicates but it doesn't prevent from being added to the table.

Comment: Why not add a `UNIQUE` index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Unique Index Constraint`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

Basically it will check for duplicates (upon one column or groups of columns) and stops insert/update operations if constraint would break.

If you're interested in how to deal with this, check out the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique)

Comment: When I adding this, in the table creation query? and how?

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there a way to add `IF NOT EXISTS` to this before creation?